# ggplot2 embed all used fonts in pdf, R

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, pdf-generation

I am plotting some figures using `qplot` and `ggplot`. Prior to the plot I call `pdf()` and save the plot with `dev.off()`. I would have to embed all the fonts in the pdf. How can I do this? Either at the time of the plot or post-process the pdf's to embed the fonts?

Comment: Are you looking for package 'extrafont'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This succeeded:

```
embedFonts( path.expand("~/Rplots.pdf") )
```

This did not, (so by experiment I have determined that `embedFonts` requires a full path and will not do "tilde expansion"):

```
embedFonts("~/Rplots.pdf")
... snipped a bunch of inscrutable error messages
GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Error in sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain), ...) : 
  object 'cmd' not found
```

although it did demonstrate that I had a functional installation of Ghostscript which is a requirement for `embedFonts`. (My copy of Ghostscript was probably from my installation of Tex.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post-process the pdf file to embed the fonts. After closing the device with `dev.off()`, you can embed the fonts with

```
embedFonts(file=filepath_fonts_not_embedded, outfile=filepath_fonts_embedded)
```